# cakephp 3.x saving multiple entities - newEntities

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, entities

I'm having the hardest time with saving multiple records. I've tried a million things, but I end up with the same problem: my records are not saved and I can't see any errors. Bear in mind that I'm new to cakephp and a novice coder.

Am I missing something obvious and crucial?

Table:

```
    $this->table('splits');
    $this->displayField('id');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

    $this->belongsTo('Transactions', [
        'foreignKey' => 'transaction_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Accounts', [
        'foreignKey' => 'account_credit_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
```

Controller:

```
    $splits = $this->Splits->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $splits = $this->Splits->newEntities($this->request->data());

        debug($splits);

        foreach ($splits as $split){
            $this->Splits->save($split);
        }
   }

    $transactions = $this->Splits->Transactions->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $accounts = $this->Splits->Accounts->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('split', 'transactions', 'accounts'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['split']);
```

Template:

```
        echo $this->Form->input('Splits.1.transaction_id', ['options' => $transactions]);
        echo $this->Form->input('Splits.1.amount',  ['type' => 'float']);
        echo $this->Form->input('Splits.1.account_id', ['options' => $accounts]);
        echo $this->Form->input('Splits.2.transaction_id', ['options' => $transactions]);
        echo $this->Form->input('Splits.2.amount',  ['type' => 'float']);
        echo $this->Form->input('Splits.2.account_id', ['options' => $accounts]);
        echo $this->Form->input('Splits.3.transaction_id', ['options' => $transactions]);
        echo $this->Form->input('Splits.3.amount',  ['type' => 'float']);
        echo $this->Form->input('Splits.3.account_id', ['options' => $accounts]);
```

Debug on $splits:

```
[
(int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Split) {

    (int) 1 => [
        'transaction_id' => '108',
        'amount' => '100.33',
        'account_id' => '2'
    ],
    (int) 2 => [
        'transaction_id' => '108',
        'amount' => '50.22',
        'account_id' => '4'
    ],
    (int) 3 => [
        'transaction_id' => '108',
        'amount' => '65.22',
        'account_id' => '5'
    ],
    '[new]' => true,
    '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [
        (int) 1 => true,
        (int) 2 => true,
        (int) 3 => true
    ],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Splits'

}
]
```

Comment: Data is not insert into the table right ?

Comment: Replace SaveAll instead save in your controller.

Comment: @KarthikKeyan There is no `saveAll()` in CakePHP 3.x

Comment: Dos you check if there were validation errors in our entities?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you somewhere saw this `Table.index.field` style being used, or did you just tried something and hoped it would work?

When saving many records respectively creating many entities, the expected format is a numerically indexed array that holds the data for the individual records, just as shown in the docs

**[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Converting Multiple Records](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#converting-multiple-records)**

> When creating forms that create/update multiple records at once you
>   can use newEntities():
>
> [...]
>
> In this situation, the request data for multiple articles should look
>   like:
>
> ```
> $data = [
>     [
>         'title' => 'First post',
>         'published' => 1
>     ],
>     [
>         'title' => 'Second post',
>         'published' => 1
>     ],
> ];
> ```

So your inputs should not use the table name, but just the index and the field name, like

```
echo $this->Form->input('0.transaction_id', /* ... */);
echo $this->Form->input('0.amount', /* ... */);
echo $this->Form->input('0.account_id', /* ... */);
echo $this->Form->input('1.transaction_id', /* ... */);
echo $this->Form->input('1.amount', /* ... */);
echo $this->Form->input('1.account_id', /* ... */);
echo $this->Form->input('2.transaction_id', /* ... */);
echo $this->Form->input('2.amount', /* ... */);
echo $this->Form->input('3.account_id', /* ... */);
```

Comment: NDM: I did see the Table.index.field syntax somewhere. I think I got hung up on validation errors, when I should have been paying more attention to getting the data formatted correctly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$splits = TableRegistry::get('splits'); 

$entities = $splits->newEntities($this->request->data());

foreach ($entities as $entity) {
    $splits->save($entity);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps he wants a loopless solution like earlier version of CakePHP had SaveAll() method...

Answer (score 0):

Try this example to insert multiple recored in cakphp 3.x

```
$passwords = $this->request->data('password_id');
foreach ($passwords as $password) {
$data = [
    'event_id'    => $this->request->data('event_id'),
    'password_id' => $password
];
$eventPasswordAll = $this->EventPasswordAll->newEntity();
$this->EventPasswordAll->patchEntity($eventPasswordAll, $data);
$this->EventPasswordAll->save($eventPasswordAll );}
```

I hope it is useful to your question

please reviwe it, Thanks !

Comment: Perhaps he wants a loopless solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you’d like to process all the entities as a single transaction you can use `transactional()`:

Although using a loop, "transations" avoids errors if the "save" does not work.

```
    // In a controller.
    $articles->getConnection()->transactional(function () use ($articles, $entities) {
        foreach ($entities as $entity) {
            $articles->save($entity, ['atomic' => false]);
        }
    });
```

[Converting Multiple Records - CakePHP 3](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#converting-multiple-records)